# Laravel 5 task scheduler (for mail queue) not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to make Laravel automatically handle the emailing queue but can't make the task scheduler working. The problem is like:

I already got jobs successfully in the database table, and in Kernel.php:

```
$schedule->command('queue:work')->everyMinute();
```

on the remote server I've run this command under the project folder:

```
* * * * * php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

But the scheduler still refuse to work, as job still remains in the table. If I manually run

```
artisan queue:work
```

the email is sent then.

What am I getting wrong here? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would *suggest* you to not use laravel's command scheduler.

Pros and cons of using laravel's task scheduler:

**pros**

Your cron task gets embedded to your code. So if you change your server you don't need to remember which all cron tasks you had.

**cons**

Let's say you have several other cron tasks. Task T1 runs every minute but task T2 runs every day while task T3 runs every Tuesday. Now to just check this you will be running a daemon which will check if every minute of you have any task in queue schedule. Also your queue should respect each jobs and their respective timings.

Instead what you can do is create separate commands for every task. And run cron jobs for them.

But even if you wanted to do what you were doing already or want to know why your cron task was not running, then here is what you were forgetting "running the artisan command in your project directory".

`* * * * * cd path_to_your_laravel_project &  php artisan schedule:run`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, guess I'd stick with it for the moment. But for your solution, didn't I already do that ..?

Comment: No. You have to do 'cd' to your project folder.

Comment: Just figured it out - it was my terrible understanding of crontab.. should have manually added the command line into the table, not just typing it. Thanks for your advice anyway:)